# Android Studio - Database Inspector : Could not launch inspector backgroundtask.inspection:

Tags: android, database, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj4BH.png)

I am using room database in my project and I started getting this error for 1-2 days. Even if I create a project from scratch and use room database, I get this error in the app inspection section. I tried many solutions such as restarting, deleting and reinstalling, or invalidate caches, but nothing worked. I don't have any error in the code. Thanks to everyone who knows the solution and tries to help.

Comment: Hi!
Try to clean the cache in a current emulator.
Try to add more memory to it.
If does not help - try to use another emulator.
Alternatively, get the latest studio and emulator updates.
Or try to open a project in an older version of AS.